# Ternary if statement involving php class

Tags: php

Can someone please explain to me the following line of php?

```
($myobjectfunction = object::function('letsgo')) ? eval($myobjectfunction) : false;
```

I understand objects and their functions. Is this php saying if `$myobjectfunction` is defined then `eval $myobjectfunction`, otherwise do nothing? Because in the code I am reading, `object` hasn't yet been defined before this line (sometimes).

Comment: There is no such thing as a "ternary if statement". Also, this construct is covered in any good PHP book, as well as _all over this site_. What research did you do?

Comment: Also, if `object` weren't defined then this code would not parse, let alone run.

Comment: I wonder what `object::function('letsgo') returns. You seem pretty sure that it does no harm when the code is eval'd. Although it's good that `eval()` exists, you really should avoid using it.

Comment: Hi Arjan, this isn't my code it is code that I am trying to understand. May I ask, why should eval() be avoided? many thanks.

Comment: You should write @username to get the attention of those you want to address. Eval is a security risk if you do not control what is put in there. For example if you eval code that was given by a user it could be malicious and you would give the user the same execution rights as your script. This is why eval is considered bad and should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

This line assigns the returned value from the function `object::function('letsgo')` to the variable `$myobjectfunction`. If the return was a "truthy" value (evaluates to boolean `TRUE`), the contents of that variable are then evaluated as PHP code ([`eval`](http://php.net/eval)). If the initial return was `FALSE`, no further action is taken. The `false` at the end basically does nothing.

This works because PHP will return the value from an assignment, even though it isn't usually used for anything. In the case of your bit of code, however, the return from the assignment is used to determine which branch of the ternary operator to take since it is enclosed in parentheses.

```
$x = 3;
// returns 3 even if we don't use it...
```

This is an unusual idiom, because the parentheses are around the initial assignment.

```
   ($myobjectfunction = object::function('letsgo')) ? eval($myobjectfunction) : false;
//^^---------------------------------------------^^^
```

A more typical usage of the ternary operator would assign the output of either side of the `?` to the variable on the left, based on the condition to the right of the `=` like:

```
$myobjectfunction = object::function('letsgo') ? $someothervalue : false;
```

Comment: And no, that would be _more_ weird in this case, since you're using `$myobjectfunction` before assigning to it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed... Example changed to reflect that.

Comment: +1 for explanation. Also agreed with the oddness, as it's not a typical use of the ternary operator. It makes it less readable.

Comment: @Nobody I actually already edited that for clarity describing a "truthy" return, probably while you were commenting.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on here. I'm assuming you have substituted actual values in order to 'simplify' the example, but the use of keywords actually clouds the matter.

The declaration of the class 'object' doesn't need to be before this statement, so long as the object class is defined at some point during the code execution.

Comment: (a) Didn't answer the question. (b) Second paragraph is wrong.

Comment: i would say it compiles and behaves in a determined way.

Comment: I don't know what version of PHP other people are working with, but from where I'm sat, that code provided by the OP is not valid PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This code is equivalent to:

```
$myobjectfunction = object::function('letsgo');

if( $myobjectfunction ) {
  eval( $myobjectfunction );
}
else {
  false;
}
```

In other words, assign the result of `object::function( 'letsgo' )` to a variable. If that variable is "truthy" (i.e. not false, null, or 0, or another value that evaluates like false) then `eval` its contents; otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

ya you pretty much got it, well its saying IF $myobjectfunction has successfully been returned a positive result (ie: not false, 0, or null) the eval the new variable object, but i probably wouldnt use "false" in the else bit., id probaby use null.

Now for this to do anything, "object" does need to be defined

this is a strange piece of code though, in my own honest opinion